# How to align text right in navigation sidedrawer

Tags: text, alignment, react-navigation

I'm trying to right align text inside a react-navigation v3 sidedrawer.

```
  drawerPosition: "right",
  drawerWidth: 280,

  contentOptions: {
   itemsContainerStyle: {
     textAlign: "right",  // nope
     alignItems: "right" // nope
   },

  itemStyle: {
   textAlign: "right". // nope
  },
 activeTintColor: "#0ca9dd",
 labelStyle: {
  fontSize: 18,
  alignItems: "right" // nope
  textAlign: "right" // nope
 },
 },
```

What very simple, basic step am I missing?

Comment: have you tried using ```alignItmes: 'flex-end'```?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happens.